# how to access the content of the textbox dynamically created in html, through flask

Tags: python, html, flask, textbox

I am dynamically creating the the textboxs by a dropdown menu with numbers, as i select the number so many textboxs get created and once i click on submit it has to post to the flask application and use the content in the textbox and print it in my CLI. But i am facing diffcuilties to get the content of the textboxs and use it in a Python flask inturn to run other processes.
i have attached the screenshot of me html page. Appreciate your help.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUUyz.png)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<body>
<label>Enter Number of Buildpacks:</label>
<select id="mySelect" onChange="onChangeDropdown()">
<option value="">Please Select....</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
</select>
<br/>
<br/>
 
<div id="demo">
</div>

<input type="submit" value="Submit" >

</body>
</html>

<script>
function onChangeDropdown(){
  var slctdValue = parseInt(document.getElementById("mySelect").value);
   document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = buildTextboxes(slctdValue);
   }
 function buildTextboxes(num){
         var html = "";
   for (var i=0; i < num; i++){
   html = html + '<br/><div><label>Buildpack Name:</label><input type="text" id="textbox"'+ i + '></div>'
   
   }
   return html;
 }
</script>
```

```
import os,re,yaml
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, redirect

port = 8080
if 'PORT' in os.environ:
    port = int(os.getenv("PORT"))


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('TestUI.html')

@app.route('/', methods=['POST','GET'])
def submit():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:

            s=request.values.get('text_1')
            s1=request.values.get('text1[0]')
            s2=request.values.get('text1[1]')
            s3=request.values.get('text1[2]')
            s4=request.values.get('text1[3]')
            s5=request.values.get('text1[4]')
            s6=request.values.get('text1[5]')
            s7=request.values.get('text1[6]')
            s8=request.values.get('text1[7]')
            s9=request.values.get('text1[8]')

            print(s,s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6,s7,s8,s9)

        except Exception as ex:

            print("Unexpected error:No Inputs for Buildpacks ")


        return redirect(e["url"], code=302)

if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=port)
    #app.run(debug=True)
```